# Combo Boxes in netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, combobox

i have a gui in netbeans. 3 textfields animal id(i.e MAM001) , type of animal(LION) and nickname(SIMBA). when the three textfields are entered the user can click on the submit button which will store the values from the three textfields in a database.

what i want to do but don't know how to do it, is to use a combo box with three different fields in it (MAMMAL,BIRD REPTILE). when i select  mammal from the combo box it will the change mysql statements in the background so that the data entered into the textfields will go into the mammal table in the database. if i click on the "bird" field in the combo box the same thing will happen except the data will go into the bird table in the database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, that you want to react on an action event on your combo box. You can do this with the help of an ItemListener. For more details see the [java api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html).

One approach could be the following:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DemoFrame {

private JFrame frame;
private JComboBox comboBox;
private String[] items = {"IT1","IT2","IT3"};

public DemoFrame() {
    frame = new JFrame("Demo Frame");
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    comboBox = new JComboBox(items);
    comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            //perform here your database querys for specific items.

            if(e.getItem().equals(items[0]) && e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                //db query for it "IT1"
            }
        }

    });

    frame.add(comboBox);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new DemoFrame();
        }
    });
}

}
```